# Linux: how can i configure dot1ad(double tag) on a interface?

Tags: linux, linux-networking

I am on SUSE, and able to configure dot1q(single tag) for an interface. How can I configure double tagging on an interface?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to add next level of dot1q tagging to an interface manually - using the **vconfig** utility.

Add a dot1q tag to interface:

```
vconfig add eth0 34
```

After this you will have a eth0.34 interface.

```
vconfig add eth0.34 56
```

This creates the eth0.34.56

See "man vconfig" for more detailed explanation.

To make the configuration permanent you need to use the configuration files in `/etc/sysconfig/network`
I'm not sure how it's done in SUSE but in case of redhat you would create a file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth3.161.34`
with the following content:

```
DEVICE=eth3.161.34
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO="static"
USERCTL=no
VLAN="yes"
IPADDR="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
NETMASK="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know you can just add another ".vlan-id" there. I got it work now.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to creat another config file for another VLAN. If you have VLAN 10 like this

```
ETHERDEVICE='eth0'
IPADDR=192.168.10.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
STARTMODE='onboot'
VLAN=yes
```

Then

> vi ifcfg-vlan11

```
ETHERDEVICE='eth0'
IPADDR=192.168.11.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
STARTMODE='onboot'
VLAN=yes
```